# SQL Recursive Query to Navigate Up and Return Top Item

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a hierarchical table used to store part builds. The schema is a simple one such that the table stores a component and its parent. `|--Component--|--Parent--|`. I'm using a Common Table Expression to build the part list from the parent parts, and this is working without issue.

The problem I'm running into is in trying to determine the top-level part from an internal component. I've tweaked the CTE to build up a part list from an internal part, but I'm running into trouble returning *only* the parent part.

This might be easier to explain using an example, so please see below. In the example, Car and Motorcycle are the two top-level parts. The only way to determine this is that they are found in the `Parent` column, but never in the `Component` column (I don't have control over the schema or the way the data is stored).

```
CREATE TABLE Build
(
    Parent      VARCHAR(20),
    Component   VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO Build
VALUES
('Car', 'Door'),
('Door', 'Handle'),
('Handle', 'Screw'),
('Motorcycle', 'Frame'),
('Frame', 'Tank'),
('Tank', 'Internals'),
('Internals', 'Screw');

DECLARE @Comp VARCHAR(20) = 'Screw';

WITH UsedPart (Parent, Component, Level)
AS
(
    SELECT
        b.Parent,
        b.Component,
        1
    FROM Build as b
    WHERE b.Component = @Comp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        b.Parent,
        b.Component,
        u.Level + 1
    FROM Build as b
    INNER JOIN UsedPart as u
    ON b.Component = u.Parent
)

SELECT
    *
FROM UsedPart
```

This returns:

```
Parent      Component   Level
----------------------------------------
Handle      Screw           1
Internals   Screw           1
Tank        Internals       2
Frame       Tank            3
Motorcycle  Frame           4    <-- Return this
Door        Handle          2
Car         Door            3    <-- Return this
```

The only solution I've come up with is to `JOIN` the above result set with a subquery like `SELECT fparent FROM Build WHERE fparent NOT IN Component` but it just seems to be an inefficient solution to the problems.

Comment: What's your expected results?

Comment: @PeterHe I tried pointing to the two records I'd expect in the result table. It should only return the two records: `Motorcycle  Frame 4` and `Car  Door  3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the select to:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM UsedPart u
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UsedPart p WHERE p.Component=u.Parent)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you could tackle this. I am sure there are others.

```
DECLARE @Comp VARCHAR(20) = 'Screw';

WITH UsedPart
AS
(
    SELECT
        b.Parent,
        b.Component,
        Level = 1,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by parent)
    FROM Build as b
    WHERE b.Component = @Comp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        b.Parent,
        b.Component,
        u.Level + 1,
        u.RowNum
    FROM Build as b
    INNER JOIN UsedPart as u
    ON b.Component = u.Parent
)
, SortedValues as
(
    SELECT *
        , MyVal = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by RowNum order by Level desc)
    FROM UsedPart
)

select *
from SortedValues
where MyVal = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Parent
from build
where Parent not in (select Component from build)
```